# Как забрать данные из базы в JavaScript?

Tags: drupal, javascript, база-данных

`Drupal` знаю плохо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне забрать данные из базы в `javascript`? Скрипт подключается в `.info` файле темы, и данные, выходит должны выводится на страницу в виде кода `javascript`. Как это сделать?

Comment: я в принципе понимаю, что лучше всего написать модуль и т.д. но сейчас поздно что-либо исправлять, поэтому подойдет любой способ

Comment: Вопрос не конкретен и не ясен. Попробуйте переформулировать его, указав, что именно у вас не получается и что надо получить в итоге. Плюс информация о том, что вы плохо знаете drupal, лишняя.

Comment: ок. в приложение js данные из базы можно передать так:

<?php
//получаем данные из базы и записываем их в переменную
$data = get_db_data();
$data = json_encode($data);
?>
<head>
<script>
//тут принимаем данные в javascript
var data = eval('('+<?php echo $data ?>+')');
</script>

<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>

как все это сделать на drupal, при условии, что myscript.js передается в шаблон через .info файл темы?

Comment: Так в myscript.js БУДЕТ доступна переменная "var data"! Мало того, она будет заполнена тем, что в нее внесет ваш php-скрипт. И тут дело вовсе не в вашей CMS.

Comment: именно, что будет. но как можно "влезть" в шапку шаблона drupal (ведь myscript.js подключается именно там), да ещё извлечь данные из базы?
я бы нафигачил запрос в базу прямл в шаблоне, но он не разрешает там выполнение функции db_query. задача в двух словах -- передать данные в подключенный в шапке скрипт

Comment: LOL, что за бред?

      var data = eval('('+<?php echo $data ?>+')');

Зачем eval то? *facepalm*

Answer (score 3):

```
    <a href="#" class="klik">Klik</a>
        <?php 
          $query = db_select('node');
          $query->addExpression('COUNT(*)');
          $count = $query->execute()->fetchField();
          print '<span id="message">Всего записей'.$count.' штук ;-) </span>';
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
            $('.klik').show();
            $('#message').hide();
            $('.klik').click(function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              $('#message').slideToggle();
            });
      });
    </script>
```